# multiplying column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql script below.

```
SELECT
     InvoiceNo
    ,InvoiceType
    ,Amount
    ,OrderAmount
    ,ShippingAmount
    ,TruckTaxAmount
    ,PreShippingAmount
FROM truckdb AS t1
INNER JOIN truckdetails AS t2 ON tl.truckdetail = t2.truckid
WHERE [shipping date] > = '01-01-2011'
```

And sample data

```
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+
| InvNo  | InvoiceType | Amount  | OrderAmount | ShippingAmount | TruckTxAmt | PreShAmt |
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+
|    001 | ckt         |    1200 |         544 |            666 |         23 |       11 |
|    002 | tkp         |    1300 |         544 |            133 |         11 |       11 |
|    009 | ckt         |    1222 |         221 |            122 |        221 |      566 |
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+
```

I have several invoice types. I want to show one particular CKT InvoiceType - Amount, OrderAmount, ShippingAmount, TruckTaxAmount in negative. I tried to multiply using when statement after where clause. But something is wrong.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Please consider using the ANSI standard YYYYMMDD format for dates. The string you have is ambiguous and can be interpreted incorrectly simply by changing the language of the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the CASE WHEN in the SELECT clause, not after the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
...
CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN Amount * -1.00 ELSE Amount END AS Amount,
CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN OrderAmount * -1.00 ELSE OrderAmount END AS OrderAmount,
(etc)
...
FROM ...
```

Comment: I did, but i have lot more columns

Comment: I want to add this logic after where clause see my code above

Comment: And I'm telling you that "after the where clause" is the wrong place to add this logic.  You can't do it there.   You must do it the way I show in my answer.   Why do you think you want to do it after the WHERE clause?

Comment: I think that the OP is confused about what a WHERE clause does. It is used to filter which rows are returned. You use the select clause to define the columns that are in the result set. That is what you are after here, not filtering out rows.

Comment: I'm having weir results. just showing Amount column in output. If i specify columns after select statement, i'm having syntax error

Comment: SELECT  InvoiceNo
    ,InvoiceType
    ,Amount
    ,OrderAmount
    ,ShippingAmount
    ,TruckTaxAmount
    ,PreShippingAmount

CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN Amount * -1.00 ELSE Amount END AS Amount,
CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN OrderAmount * -1.00 ELSE OrderAmount END AS OrderAmount,

FROM tbl

Comment: The above query would have a syntax error because of the comma between `OrderAmount` and `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Tab Alleman

```
SELECT ... CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN Amount * -1.00 ELSE    Amount END AS Amount, 
      CASE WHEN InvoiceType='CKT' THEN OrderAmount * -1.00 ELSE OrderAmount END AS 
          OrderAmount, (etc) ... FROM ...    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```